# Error 1222 on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1222

I'm facing this error...
Error Code: 1222 on MySQL: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

This is my code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`() 
BEGIN 
   SELECT ID, Name 
   FROM attributes into @resultset; 
END
```

Comment: Isn't it self-explanatory?  You're selecting 2 columns into a table `resultset` that has some other number than 2 columns.

Comment: @dbaseman: `@resultset` is a user variable, not a table.

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [`SELECT ... INTO` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) (my emphasis added):

> The `INTO` clause can name a list of one or more variables, which can be user-defined variables, stored procedure or function parameters, or stored program local variables (see [Section 13.6.4, “Variables in Stored Programs”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-variables.html)). The selected values are assigned to the variables. ***The number of variables must match the number of columns.*** The query should return a single row. If the query returns no rows, a warning with error code 1329 occurs (`No data`), and the variable values remain unchanged. If the query returns multiple rows, error 1172 occurs (`Result consisted of more than one row`). If it is possible that the statement may retrieve multiple rows, you can use `LIMIT 1` to limit the result set to a single row.
>
> ```
> SELECT id, data INTO @x, @y FROM test.t1 LIMIT 1;
> ```